# A preposition for "derive"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I have this sentence:

> Moreover, spelling’s error patterns and statistical trends can be derived **(from /by/through/by means of)** the software.

It means that the software outputs some statistical results in which some patterns can be discovered.

What is the best preposition for my meaning. Or even an equivalent sentence. "From" is the collocation word but I am afraid it is not applicable here.

Comment: I might not use a preposition: _trends can be derived **using** the software_.

Comment: And I might not use the passive: The software can discern error patterns and spot trends.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you!, the challenge of nested contexts now turns to spelling patterns! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to say:

> X is **derived from** Y.

In this case Y is what forms the basis for X, so X is based on Y.

> X is **derived through** Y.

Here Y is what performs the action, but X is derived **from** something else. Y just makes the action of deriving happen.

> X is **derived by** Y.

In this case, Y would most likely be an action that starts the action of deriving. For example:

> You can derive X from Y **by** clicking Z.

In your sentence, **through** would fit best as I suppose it is the software that does the deriving for the user.

Comment: But you didn't say your suggestion, I myself thing "using" or "by means of" is appropriate here

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure what meaning you're looking for. I suppose it is the software that allows for the process of deriving to happen. So if that is the case, I would go for **through**.

Comment: Yes sure it is, can you imagine that something is derived from software?!

Comment: Well, yes! Software can be derived from other software. But in your case, indeed, **from** would not fit.

Answer (score 0):

X is derived from Y - X is something we obtained from Y.

X is derived by Y - Y is a method or tool used to obtain X.  What X was derived from is not said.

X is derived through Y - this means the same as X derived by Y.

Comment: But you didn't say your suggestion, I myself thing "using" or "by means of" is appropriate here